# Select rows where id is in multiple ranges

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table called `postcode_ranges`

```
id | city_id | from |   to
---------------------------
 1 |       1 | 1000 | 1999
 2 |       1 | 2000 | 2000
 3 |       1 | 2030 | 2050
 4 |       2 | 1000 | 1000
 5 |       5 | 4300 | 4400
 6 |       6 | 9000 | 9900
```

The `city_id` is a foreign key to a `properties` table, which has a column `postcode_digits`.

Now, I want to be able to select all properties that belong to a certain city. This means that when someone picks the city with `id = 1`, all rows in the `properties` table should be selected where the `postcode_digits` column is beteen 1000 and 1999, or 2000 and 2000 (seems easier when automating it in a query), or between 2030 and 2050.

If possible, I'd like to have this all in one neat query, but I don't exactly know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
    FROM properties 
        INNER JOIN postcode_ranges 
        ON postcode_ranges.city_id = properties.city_id 
            AND properties.postcode >= postcode_ranges.from 
            AND properties.postcode <= postcode_ranges.to
    WHERE postcode_ranges.city_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want a `join` with a `where`?

```
select p.*
from properties p join
     postcode_ranges pr
     on p.postcode between p."from" and p."to"
where pr.city_id = 1;
```